# JAVA, Eclipse does not launch an application, error: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform

Tags: java, eclipse, 64-bit

I'm getting this error when i try to run as JAVA application:

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   C:\Users\Mindaugas\GCMDLN.DLL: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD
>   64-bit platform"

I can run the same code as JAVA applet - no problem.

Here is the source code:

```
import acm.graphics.*;
import acm.program.*;

public class GraphicsTry extends GraphicsProgram {
    public void run() {
        GRect brick = new GRect(5,5,5,6);
        add(brick);
    }// run
}// GraphicsTry
```

I have read some posts, cause this issue has appeared to others as well. There seem to be only two solutions: (i) recompile the GCMDLN.DLL to run 64 bit OS or (ii) install a 32-bit JVM.

Qestions: 
1. How to recompile GCMDLN.DLL file?
2. Why are the other much more complex graphic programs that use the same libraries, the same methods and objects (GRect) run, and this one does not? 
3. Why such difference betwen JAVA applet and application? Isn't GCMDLN.DLL used by both?
4. Are there any other possible solutions?

Comment: 1. Where is the source to GCMDLN.DLL?  I'm not familiar with that DLL.  At the very least you'll need the source code of this DLL and a compiler for whatever language the source is written in.  2. What other programs?  3. Which browser are you running?  Is it 32-bit or 64-bit?  Perhaps it's a 32-bit browser with a 32-bit JVM plugin.  In short, the two solutions you mention are the only solutions.  FYI, this restriction is due to the OS, not to Java - a 64-bit process cannot load a 32-bit DLL, and vice versa.

Comment: 1. Why are other programs running - different classes, so different objects and in different projects, but from the description of the problem that shouldn't relate in any way to the problem. 2. I don't have anything AMD'ish in my machine as far as I know - it's Intel CPU, SiS chipset system. What's all that about?

Comment: I'm afraid you're still not providing anywhere near enough details for anybody to be able to answer why 'only' this program fails to run.  Are you absolutely sure these mysterious other programs you say so little about all run in 64-bit Java and are successfully able to load that 32-bit DLL of yours?  As for AMD64, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64.